# Physical host or VM

Tags: virtual-machine

Is there a way to tell whether a host is a physical one or a VM and which virtual container it is running out of (e.g. VirtualBox or VMWare)?  I was wondering if that info may be in `/etc` some place.

Comment: any chance cat /etc/issue will bring something? Or some uname variant?

Comment: i get `Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS \n \l` from `/etc/issue`

Comment: dmesg | grep bare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can install the facter package, and then

```
facter virtual
```

will tell you if it is a virtual.

or you can use dmidecode to examine your system. look for Product Name in the output.

Comment: I did run facter on my machine and I get
facter virtual
vmware_server

But this is a real ubuntu machine. I do have a vmware machine turned off here. Am I missunderstanding the usage of facter?

Comment: yeah in this case, it is telling you that it is a virtual machine host (not a vm, which will just say vmware). what is the Product Name if you run dmidecode? In my experience, dmidecode is more intuitive to understand.

Comment: yes, it worked on my Ubuntu VM

Comment: @johnshen64 no idea:
dmidecode | grep product
returns empty

Comment: use grep -i, as you are using difference cases than the string that I listed. thanks!

Comment: @johnshen64 what does it mean?
 Product Name: POS-MIG31AE
 Product Name: POS-MIG31AE

Comment: that is a physical machine and what you see is the motherboard name: http://browser.primatelabs.com/geekbench2/1021447, you would see something like virtual or vmware etc. if it were a vm.

Answer (score 1):

There is usually no information in `/etc` that you can use to detect if the host is running as a VM.

But you can look at the hardware in `/proc` and  `/sys` or (better) use tools like `lspci`.

The easiest way, however, is to use [`imvirt`](http://micky.ibh.net/~liske/imvirt.html), which does exactly what you need. It supports lots of different VMs. At least in Debian-based distributions you can install it via the package manager.